# LLVM 3.4 tag modified instructions

Tags: llvm

I'm would like to be able to detect which part of a program has been modified by a previous LLVM pass.

How can I tag instruction / basic blocks and function such as I can retrieve that a pass P1 has previously modified this part of the code ?

I would like to achieve something like:

```
// First pass
...
tag<bool>(instruction, "modified");


// Second pass
if(has_tag<bool>(instruction, "modified"))
    do_something...
```

Is there a feature in LLVM allowing to make such tag system ?

Comment: It sounds as if you want to implement a diff. LLVM contains no such thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to look at the LLVM diff engine in its the toolset:
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/tools/llvm-diff/llvm-diff.cpp